# Using a server response for pageLoadErrorMessage in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Although you can change the default error response in JQuery Mobile doing something like:

```js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = 'This is my custom error.';
});￼
```

I would like to use the errors I am returning from the actual application, which allows me to set different messages depending on the error.

For example, with a `Forbidden` error I would want to display something that correlates to that issue.

I have the flexibility to return the responses as JSON if that would be more palatable for JQuery, I am just not sure how to get the `pageLoadErrorMessage` to consume that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pageloadfailed`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) event for that.

```js
$(document).on("pageloadfailed", function(event, data){
    event.preventDefault();

    var errMessage = data.xhr.status + " " + data.xhr.statusText;

    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:errMessage, textonly:true, textVisible: true});
    },50);

    setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.loading('hide')}, 2000);

    data.deferred.reject(data.absUrl, data.options);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/5m8kj/)

Comment: I've been playing with a number of approaches with `pageloadfailed` but was not able to get this far. I will try this, thank you!

Comment: This totally worked. I will update this with some JSON I am returning as a message :) Thanks again!